# Exporting to Excel in Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, jsf, apache-poi

I use Apache POI to export data in excel format. The import goes well, but when I try to open the document I have this message "Excel has encountered an unreadable content in the document "toto.xls". Would you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If the source of this workbook is reliable click yes. "

Below is the java code of export excel

```
    public void exportExcel() throws IOException {

    // Creation workbook vide
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // Creation d'une feuille vierge
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Participant");
    List<toto> totoList = this.getAllToto;
    int indiceMap = 2;
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] { "name", "surname" });

    for (TotoBean l : totoList) {
        data.put(Integer.toString(indiceMap),
                new Object[] { l.getName(), l.getSurname() });
        indiceMap++;
    }
    // Iteration sur la map data et ecriture dans dans la feuille excel
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        }
    }

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String dateToday = dateFormat.format(new Date());

    // Ecriture du fichier excel comme attachement
    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(outByteStream);
    byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
    String fileOut = "Liste-toto[" + this.getCity() + "]"
            + dateToday + ".xlsx";
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + fileOut + "\"");

    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(outArray);

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: I think XSSFSheet creates an .xslx document, not an .xls document

Comment: Thanks for your reply but xslx is not recognize as excel document

Comment: Sorry I mean xlsx of course...

Comment: Yes I agree with you and it is also the extension of my generated file "Liste-toto.xlsx" , but the excel application is not able to open it without previously displayed the error message contained in my post.

Comment: I suspect it might be a problem with the content type. Take a look at http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php. If that doesn't help, try to reduce the problem. Maybe start with an empty file without data.

Comment: Does your cell.setCellValue((String) obj); probably put some un-allowed characters into the cell? I think Excel is a bit confused, when you have , or . as cell content.

Comment: Even when I create an empty sheet (Without  data) I have the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the mis-match of these two lines

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

and

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

If you really want to generate a `.xls` older-style Excel workbook, you need to change the first line to be `HSSFWorkbook` rather than `XSSFWorkbook`

If you do mean to generate a `.xlsx` Excel workbook, then the content type on the second line needs to be the correct .xlsx one, which would be:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider opening it "As Adminstrator". According to this ( https://superuser.com/questions/401714/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-excel-found-unreadable-content-in-filename ) its a work around.